Xcode 16.0 : unexpected service error: The Xcode build system has crashed
I recently upgraded my Xcode to version 16. After the upgrade i have started encountering this error when i am building my app.
unexpected service error: The Xcode build system has crashed. Build again to continue.


My Setup

macOS: version 15
react-native version 0.73.8

Has anyone encountered this issue or how to resolve this build system crash?

Can you try Product -> Scheme -> edit Scheme, and change build order to Dependency Order?

I was having same issue earlier today on macOS Sequoia and XCode 16, then I tried using command line
yarn ios --simulator "iPhone 16 Pro Max"

xcodebuild complained about react-native-image-crop-picker
ScanDependencies /Users/hi/Downloads/AppFolder/ios/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNImageCropPicker.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ImageCropPicker.o /Users/hi/Downloads/AppFolder/node_modules/react-native-image-crop-picker/ios/src/ImageCropPicker.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'RNImageCropPicker' from project 'Pods')

Solution
I upgraded react-native-image-crop-picker from version 0.40.3 to 0.41.2 (latest) and the error is gone.

The issue has been resolved here -> https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker/pull/2068

I upgraded react-native-image-crop-picker from version 0.40.3 to 0.41.2 (latest) and resolved

wow, i can't believe it but this solved for me also.

But why we need react-native library if our project is in native language. like swift, objective-c –

Same problem after update to Xcode 16.
Fixed by upgrading react-native-image-crop-picker from version "0.40.3" to "0.41.2" as mentioned before

I was getting the same issue after upgrade to iOS 18 and Xcode 16:

unexpected service error: The Xcode build system has crashed. Build
again to continue.

This issue is coming due to react-native-image-crop-picker package
How to fix:
Upgrade from react-native-image-crop-picker@0.40.3 to react-native-image-crop-picker@0.41.2
yarn upgrade react-native-image-crop-picker@0.41.2

If required Navigate to iOS folder and update pod related to this package or just do:
pod update

Now just rebuild.

But why we need react-native library if our project is in native language. like swift, objective-c

you can't use this library in native project. If you are getting same error in Native then it could be due to some other pod library or any other cause. Attach the comment error message in comment for better understanding

Solution
I upgraded react-native-image-crop-picker from version 0.40.3 to 0.41.2 (latest) and the error is gone.

I encountered the same issue earlier today. I’m currently using react-native-image-crop-picker, but simply updating it didn’t resolve the problem. I also have lottie-react-native in my project, and upgrading it to version 7.0.0 (npm install lottie-react-native@latest), along with updating lottie-ios to 4.5.0 (npm install lottie-ios@latest), ended up fixing the issue for me.
If others are running into similar Xcode-related issues, I’d suggest reviewing your installed modules, particularly any that might rely on native iOS components. Upgrading them to the latest stable versions could be a potential fix. In my case, digging into the Xcode crash log helped me track down the root cause related to the Lottie integration.
Hope this helps!

This answer could use some more love - we are also out of date on all 3 of those libraries, so hopefully that does the trick for us as well.

Thank you! This solution worked perfectly for me as well. It’s good to know that the issue with react-native-image-crop-picker 0.40.0 can be identified when building the app using Xcode via the terminal. Building directly through Xcode doesn’t always catch this specific error, but running the build from the command line using the following script revealed the problem.
yarn ios --simulator "iPhone 16 Pro"

Upgrading to version 0.41.2 or letest resolved the issue without any further complications.
yarn upgrade react-native-image-crop-picker@0.41.2

Navigate to iOS folder and update pod related to this package
cd ios && pod install && cd ..

Then build the app again.
yarn ios --simulator "iPhone 16 Pro"

