The React Native project cannot be built after upgrading Xcode to version 16.0
I'm currently facing an issue where my React Native project fails to build after upgrading to Xcode 16.0. I'm using React Native version 0.72.
Steps I have tried:
I deleted the DerivedData folder to reset the Xcode cache, but this did not solve the problem.
The build system crashes with the following error:
"The Xcode build system has crashed. Build again to continue."
I've attached a screenshot of the error for reference. Does anyone have suggestions on what might be causing this issue or any additional steps I could take to resolve it?


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78995007/xcode-16-0-unexpected-service-error-the-xcode-build-system-has-crashed
